Why do we use “la” in this sentence?
I have read these sentences:

“Mandy aura beaucoup de travail la semaine prochaine.”
“Lundi prochain, elle fera sa lessive comme d’habitude.”
“Le repassage et le ménage attendront mardi et mercredi prochains.”

I’m a bit confused here. When do we use a definite article before (…) prochain(e)?

Welcome to fr.SE. The article is required as well in Mandy aura beaucoup de travail {le mois prochain | les jours prochains | le jour suivant } etc. Only the case for day names requires special handling.
Lundi prochain w/out article is specifically next Monday, counting from today. Alternatively, it could be le prochain lundi, where the article is mandated by the anteposed adjective, not by the day name.
The article would be required in the plural: les lundis prochains or, stylistically better, les prochains lundis, meaning the next few Mondays.
Finally, Mandy aura beaucoup de travail le lundi is possible w/out adjective, meaning every Monday. Note, the verbe in the future tense is unexpected: specific context is required to justify it. It nuances every Monday as every Monday, starting with the next.
